# How to use multiple scanners of different types in java?

Tags: java, input

I have this code in Java (executed on the default Eclipse console) :

```
String name = "";
    System.out.printf("Name of the Story Arc:  ");

    if(in.hasNext()) {
        name = in.nextLine();
    }

    int l = 0;
    System.out.printf("Length of the Story Arc:  ");
    if(in.hasNextInt()) {
        l = in.nextInt();
    }

    StoryArc a = new StoryArc(name, id, issues_nb + 1, l);
    story_arcs.add(a);
```

I am trying to execute it multiple times in a row but it behaves weirdly : 
The first execution works fine, asking the name, then the length. The second execution, it asks the name, but not the length (set to 0). The third execution asks the length, but sets the name to "", and it loops like that, with length on even executions and name on odd ones.

It's one of my first program in Java so I suppose I didn't understand something with scanners, but I couldn't figure it out after long researches, so please help.

**edit:**
Thank you all! With you help we managed to make it work!

Comment: can you please post your full code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.Your code has no problem but after you can run this may be it will help you

```
import java.util.*;

public class Answer {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String name = "";
        System.out.printf("Name of the Story Arc:  ");
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        if(in.hasNext()) {
            name = in.nextLine();
        }

        int l = 0;
        System.out.printf("Length of the Story Arc:  ");
        if(in.hasNextInt()) {
            l = in.nextInt();
        }

        System.out.println("Name of the Story Arc: "+name);
        System.out.println("Length of the Story Arc:  "+l);


    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

`l = in.nextInt()` will only get the integer, but doesn't indicate you're done inputting that line, so you'll have to tell the Scanner that yourself. There are two ways to do this:

You can do a `in.nextLine();` to indicate we're done with the line containing the integer:

Change `l = in.nextInt();` to:

```
l = in.nextInt();
if(in.hasNext()){
  // Ignore the rest of the line that contained the length integer-input:
  in.nextLine();
}
```

[**Try it online.**](https://tio.run/##fVFLb4JAEL7zKyacIA34Si8Sm/RoYr3YW9PDFgZci4NZBlvT@Nvp8CrEqid295vvMR87dVTeLvosyzBVeQ4vStOPBXAoPlIdQs6K5XPMdAR7gZwNG03J2zsotxoD2ImAX7BO/U2oiNCAJlgA4dd/yNmccsa9r8kNanKcGUcTg17MAtCe9zQOoNUFaKyA1B5F0LaD7r0RyQr2DzLBsWOvq5ksBt6i0DJzgmcTzgFs8WlZOhYnf6vyNX6z47rQ2UDnIDAJttKEjtuZnW@YptS6IjEajOZgP1Q6A0PZKxXZ8Z3cK6SEt7eSXwm@pIvsaR@8xoI/5HLhngMwGsEyocxg7Wsw5y5DKtvLQTGEGbH8cYya9yapxMYEjafpUPB8oHi1vL6@ezW2JQyKTFuFinW2zmX5WiWs655Yk7HVX6fW9HFwnVmTx18)

Alternatively, you can use `in.nextLine()` for all your inputs, and convert the String to an integer yourself:

Change `l = in.nextInt();` to:

```
String input = in.nextLine();
// Verify the entire line only contains the integer:
if(input.matches("\\d+")){
  l = Integer.parseInt(input);
} else{
  // TODO: Validation message: not a valid integer
}
```

[**Try it online.**](https://tio.run/##jZIxb9swEIV3/YoHTRICK3aCLDJcoECXAGkyOMiSZGCkk02XOhok7dYI/NudkyzFQlsXnQTq7r33HY8rtVWjVfnjcCiM8h7fleb3CFhv3owu4IMK8tlaXaKWUjIPTvPi@RUqbdqAlRhkm6BNNi8UMzloxgxMP/8sJfOdD1RnmtNpK66sSzQH6Nn1FHo0@jKeovMFjlFgVZMYxvG0/380sZuQraUjVEl83/TYCmFJIrNuh6@uyIFYcjqVriQpWyp/T79CkqboY9AnSJmldqeZkrQP258JNdylEgdyVOaILxqfQaDMZcR2/A/uO@JFWJ4j/wv4Lf/G3l2S5vUmnJsBuLzEEzld7docQdaOYKQJls0OheUgy/VtVchoQS7/FLcAYp/VKhRL8kn88lJexGl6okA76e1Rma2V89SQtrIBxh5kPA1lAvb48O0hx5MyupS3Zhk1ea8WlINtgMK2qfRUJ6v/2E93u4MNmQ6mUe2j/eHwSD6g3eMkmoyj0/EquroZHK@jyc0H)

Answer (score 0):

You need a `while` loop to get a valid `name` and also 
you need a `while` loop with `try/catch` to get `l`, because the user could input an invalid value instead of a valid integer:

```
String name = "";
while (name.trim().length() == 0) {
    System.out.print("Name of the Story Arc:  ");
    name = in.nextLine();
}

int l = 0;
boolean valid = false;
while (!valid) {
    try {
        System.out.print("Length of the Story Arc:  ");
        l = in.nextInt();
        valid = (l > 0);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```